# Error generating "Auth n Auth" user token from Developer Dashboard

Tags: ebay

I'm trying to generate "Auth n Auth" token for testing from ebay developer dashboard and then signing into my sandbox account. I'm able to sign in successfully but getting the following error when I click the authorization grant button:

```
There was an error passing information between the third party you just came from and eBay.
Error code: : 2022-10-23 11:04:50 : signin.sandbox.ebay.com

This error may have occurred for one of the following reasons:

The third party that has sent you here has provided invalid information to eBay.
eBay has encountered an error processing your request.
Please click on the Url and return to the third party application.
```

[image]